# Replace NA values with a fractional increase in previous values

Tags: r, tidyverse, missing-data

If I have the following dataframe

```
df <- tribble(
      ~year, ~value,
      2011, 10,
      2012, 15,
      2013, 20,
      2014, NA,
      2015, NA
    )
```

and I want to fill the NA values for 2014 and 2015 with 10% increase in previous values, so that for 2014 it'll be 22 and for 2015 it'll be 24.2. I know how to fill it with previous or next value but couldn't find any information this situation. A way to work with dplyr pipes would be more helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` in base R :

```
Reduce(function(x, y) if(is.na(y)) x * 1.1 else y, df$value, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 10.0 15.0 20.0 22.0 24.2
```

---

If you want a `tidyverse` solution use `accumulate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(value = accumulate(value, ~if(is.na(.y)) .x * 1.1 else .y))

#   year value
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2011  10  
#2  2012  15  
#3  2013  20  
#4  2014  22  
#5  2015  24.2
```

`.x` and `.y` in `accumulate` (or `x` and `y` in `Reduce`) are the current value and next value respectively. So for the first iteration `.x` is 10 and `.y` is 15, for next `.x` will become 15 and `.y` will be 20 and so on for all the values in `df$value`. We check here if the next value (`.y`) is `NA` then replace the next value with 1.1 times the previous value (`.x`) and if it is not `NA` keep it as it is.

Comment: Could you please explain what's happening in the second argument of accumulate in the tidyverse solution, specifically the use of ~ before if?

Comment: I added some explanation in the main answer. `~` is a formula based syntax which is an alternative to anonymous function. In base R option we use `function(x, y)`. In `purrr` we do the same with `~`.

Answer (score 0):

Base R using `rep()`-etition and `cumprod()` in a vectorised computation:

```
multiplier <- 1.1
is_na <- is.na(df$value)
df$value[is_na] <- with(
  df, 
  tail(cumprod(c(tail(value[!is_na], 1), rep(multiplier, sum(is_na)))), -1)
)
```

OR using a `while()` loop:

```
multiplier <- 1.1 
while(any(is.na(df$value))){
  idx <- with(df, head(which(is.na(value)), 1))
  df$value[idx] <- with(
    df, 
    value[(idx-1)] * multiplier
  )
}
```

OR using recursion:

```
multiplier <- 1.1 
cum_prod_estimate <- function(vec, multiplier=1.1){
  if(all(!(is.na(vec)))){
    return(vec)
  }else{
    idx <- Position(is.na, vec)
    vec[idx] <- vec[idx-1] * multiplier
    return(cum_prod_estimate(vec))
  }
}

df$value <- cum_prod_estimate(df$value)
```